# How to specify select among ambiguous mapping methods in nested Mapstruct mappers?

Tags: java, mapstruct

We have a particular case in which a Mapstruct mapper can choose between 2 different alternative methods from its dependency (namely ProductionPlanDetailAutoMapper), but, unable to do so, returns a compile error `SupplyPlanProjectionAutoMapper.java Can't map map value "java.util.List<ProductionPlanDetail>" to "java.util.List<ProductionPlanDetailDTO> ". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "java.util.List<ProductionPlanDetailDTO> map(java.util.List<ProductionPlanDetail> value)".`

The source code is composed of 2 mappers : an overview is presented as well as their respective codes:

[image: Mapstruct Diagram]

Mapper 1:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses={ProductionPlanDetailAutoMapper.class}) 
public interface SupplyPlanProjectionAutoMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "material.id", target = "materialId")
    public PlanningProjectionDTO convert(PlanningProjection);
    
    public Map<PlanningProjectionDTO, List<ProductionPlanDetailDTO>> convertMapProductionPlanDetail (Map<PlanningProjection, List<ProductionPlanDetail>> map);
}
```

Mapper 2:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses={RecipeAutoMapper.class})
public interface ProductionPlanDetailAutoMapper {
    
    @Mapping(source = "location.id", target = "locationId")
    @Mapping(source = "receitaProducaoOperacao", target = "productionRecipeOperation")
    @Mapping(source = "dataReferencia", target = "referenceDate")
    @Named(value = "convertWithRecipeDetail")
    public ProductionPlanDetailDTO convertWithRecipeDetail(ProductionPlanDetail);
                
    @Mapping(source = "receitaProducaoOperacao.listaTecnica.materialOutput.id", target = "outputMaterialId")
    @Mapping(source = "receitaProducaoOperacao.listaTecnica.id", target = "billOfMaterialsId")
    @Mapping(source = "receitaProducaoOperacao.receitaProducaoOperacaoCompositeKey.receitaProducao.id", target = "productionRecipeId")
    @Mapping(source = "receitaProducaoOperacao.recursoProdutivo.id", target = "productionResourceId")
    @Mapping(source = "receitaProducaoOperacao.receitaProducaoOperacaoCompositeKey.posicaoOperacao", target = "productionRecipeOperationSequence")
    @Mapping(source = "location.id", target = "locationId")
    @Mapping(source = "dataReferencia", target = "referenceDate")
    @Named(value = "convertWithoutRecipeDetail") 
    public ProductionPlanDetailDTO convertWithoutRecipeDetail(ProductionPlanDetail productionPlanDetail);

    @Named(value = "convertToListWithRecipeDetail") 
    @IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "convertWithRecipeDetail") 
    public List<ProductionPlanDetailDTO> convertToDTOListWithRecipeDetail (List<ProductionPlanDetail> productionPlanDetailList);
    
    @Named(value = "convertToListWithoutRecipeDetail") 
    @IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "convertWithoutRecipeDetail") 
    public List<ProductionPlanDetailDTO> convertToDTOListWithoutRecipeDetail (List<ProductionPlanDetail> productionPlanDetailList);
}
```

Ambiguities between methods inside the second mapper are resolved by the conjunction of @Name and @IterableMapping#QualifiedByName

We have tried the same method by attaching the below annotation to the convertMapProductionPlanDetail method, to no avail:

```
@IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "convertToListWithRecipeDetail")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not in the documentation the Mapstruct developers have already thought about it. While combing the documentation I've found this : [valueQualifiedByName](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/MapMapping.html#valueQualifiedByName--)

The solution was to use MapMapping and specify which of the 2 @Name methods should be used to populate the Values section (where List(ProductionPlanDetail) resides) of the map :

```
@MapMapping(valueQualifiedByName = "convertToDTOListWithRecipeDetail")
public Map<PlanningProjectionDTO, List<ProductionPlanDetailDTO>> convertMapProductionPlanDetail (Map<PlanningProjection, List<ProductionPlanDetail>> map);
```

Which solves the problem quite elegantly. On the other side, if the conversion issue resided in the map key, @MapMapping#keyQualifiedByName should be used instead.